# Maven resources plugin conflict

Tags: maven, resources, hierarchy, conflict, pom.xml

I have a complex pom hierarchy structure. Some of them have a resource plugin configuration that copies resources to the target artifact.
The issue I'm facing is that when I add a new resource configuration to a low level pom, the existing resource plugin configuration on its parent poms stop working.
I'm really not sure if what I'm trying to achieve is possible or not because I couldn't find any documentation about it. If it's possible, I don't know if there is any restriction to it..

I hope Some of you guys can give me a hint on this..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this from the pom reference

> You can control how child POMs inherit configuration from parent POMs
>   by adding attributes to the children of the configuration element. The
>   attributes are combine.children and combine.self. Use these attributes
>   in a child POM to control how Maven combines plugin configuration from
>   the parent with the explicit configuration in the child.
>
> Here is the child configuration with illustrations of the two
>   attributes:
>
> ```
> <configuration>   
>    <items combine.children="append">
>     <!-- combine.children="merge" is the default -->
>     <item>child-1</item>   
>   </items>   
>   <properties combine.self="override">
> <!-- combine.self="merge" is the default -->
>   <childKey>child</childKey>   
>   </properties> 
>  </configuration>
> ```

or if you want a more detailed explanation read [this post](http://blog.sonatype.com/people/2011/01/maven-how-to-merging-plugin-configuration-in-complex-projects/#.UoI-9-LwhI0)

Basically, you need to merge the parent and the child configuration of the maven-resource-plugin

Answer (score 0):

The Maven documentation isn't very clear on which POM elements merge and which do not, so a while ago I created some test POMs and played with them a bit.  In my tests with Maven 3.0.x, any `resource` (or `testResource`) elements in child POMs fully overwrite anything provided by the parent, the elements are not merged.  I found that I had to duplicate all of the parent resource config if I needed to add a resource config element in the child.

@Hilikus' answer is the correct way to do it for plugin configuration, so if it's the `maven-resource-plugin` configuration that needs to change, follow those directions.